# Specifying name for compiled class with javac

Tags: java, javac

I have a class called `fence.java` and after compilation with javac the .class file is named `fence.class`, but I want it to be called `p1`. When compiling C files with gcc I am able to do this by using the -o option but for javac I haven't been able to find something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a convention used in Java that you cannot change. The file should be called the same way as the class it contains.

Comment: The second sentence in your answer is only true for public classes.

Answer (score 0):

In java the class file name are determined by the name of the source files and that is done automatically by the compiler, if you want to use the name `p1` then change the name of the source file to that before compiling (When you do this remember to change the class name as well as the name of the file.)

Comment: The first sentence in your question is only true for public classes.